# How to receive publish/message event from Sails server using Socket.io swift client

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

Currently i am building app using Sails server as a backend and iOS Swift as a client.

I am able to emit from iOS side to create user and receive data from server side, but i am not able to get PubSub methods(message, publishAdd, Update,etc) provided by sails.

Here is my server side code

```
User.subscribe(req, [userdata.id]);
```

Now when there is any update occurred on above User recored then i need to receive event like

```
socket.on("userupdate") { data in
    print("user 1 ------------>", socket)
}
```

But i am not receiving any event on client side.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually i am missing watch on server side also need to do changes on client side like below

```
socket.onAny({ data in
    print("ANy event =====> \(data)" )
})
socket.on("user", callback: {
    data,ack in        
    print("call back called \(data)    \(ack)")        
})
```

socket.OnAny user to trace which event being called while there is any event for publish, update,etc

Here are server side changes i have done

```
User.subscribe(req, newUser, ['message']);
User.watch(req);
User.publishCreate(newUser);
```

Hope this will be useful for developer looking to implemented socket with Sails server.